# How do not show number before changing it to image ? ( jQuery counter )

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using beatiful jQuery counter you can look at it here - https://github.com/sophilabs/jquery-counter , but I have trouble with it.

When page has a lot of content ( images, other ), in Firefox it firstly show:

[image]

and after it shows:

[image]

The number is ther same, but I mean it firstly showing text, and then showing image.

Only additional css was:

```
.counter_class 
{
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

and HTML:

```
 <div class="counter_class">
  <span class="counter" data-direction="up" data-interval="1"
         data-format="999999" ><%= @counter %></span>
 </div>
```

Can someone suggest how can I fix this without damaging performance ?

Comment: place counter css at top of head section

Comment: Seems that your content is replaced on the fly, if you don't want that you can hide your div in css and show it in jQuery on document ready.

Comment: @Fry_95, it is already done `$(document).ready(function(){
$('.counter').counter({interval: 1000});...` or I didn't undesrstood you

Comment: @Hameed, I need to place it in direct place. I will add all relavant html

Comment: Nope, something like `.counter_class { display: none; }` at first, then after your jquery call to counter `$('.counter_class').show();` or try to speed up your page somehow.

Comment: @Fry_95, thanks. Please add answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your content is replaced on the fly, if you don't want that you can hide your div in css and show it in jQuery on document ready.

Try something like `.counter_class { display: none; }` at first, then after your jquery call to counter `$('.counter_class').show();` or try to speed up your page somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

- Place the CSS file on top of the head section.
- Preload the images before displaying the page.
- Show a default image, that will be replaced after the image is loaded

Good luck!